# DNN site require login twice

Tags: dotnetnuke

When I changed DNN site domain from subdomain.domain.com to domain.com login module not working properly. All users must enter data twice to log in. In DNN event viewer is message 'properly login... ' after first attempt.

i also noticed that domains are switching from my.domain.com to www.mydomain.com, while got i logout 
I am also using canonical urls in portal alias settings in site settings

Please suggest any thing as this is causing lots of issue

Thanks

Manish singh

Comment: Could it be a problem in the portal alias table? Check which one is set to primary. (just a suggestion, i don't know if this is correct)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out issue i have updated default domain in admin setting, that solved my problem

Domain aliases -Admin > Site Settings